# How to replace repeated instances of a character with a single instance of that character in python

Tags: python, string

I want to replace repeated instances of the `"*"` character within a string with a single instance of `"*"`. For example if the string is `"***abc**de*fg******h"`, I want it to get converted to `"*abc*de*fg*h"`.

I'm pretty new to python (and programming in general) and tried to use regular expressions and string.replace() like:

```
import re    
pattern = "***abc**de*fg******h"
pattern.replace("*"\*, "*")
```

where `\*` is supposed to replace all instances of the "*" character. But I got: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character.

I also tried to manipulate it with a for loop like:

```
def convertString(pattern):
for i in range(len(pattern)-1):
    if(pattern[i] == pattern[i+1]):
        pattern2 = pattern[i]
return pattern2
```

but this has the error where it only prints "*" because pattern2 = pattern[i] constantly redefines what pattern2 is...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a follow-up question on this. I have a set of characters - say {'\n', '\t', ' '}.. and I want to replace any of them recurring more than once with a single instance of that specific character. So, multiple tabs to 1 tab, multiple newlines to 1 newline, and so on... I don't want to do write multiple regexes for that. Is that possible?? Like replacing using a lookback. Any ideas?

Answer (score 35):

The naive way to do this kind of thing with `re` is

```
re.sub('\*+', '*', text)
```

That replaces runs of 1 or more asterisks with one asterisk. For runs of exactly one asterisk, that is running very hard just to stay still. Much better is to replace runs of **TWO or more** asterisks by a single asterisk:

```
re.sub('\*\*+', '*', text)
```

This can be well worth doing:

```
\python27\python -mtimeit -s"t='a*'*100;import re" "re.sub('\*+', '*', t)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.2 usec per loop

\python27\python -mtimeit -s"t='a*'*100;import re" "re.sub('\*\*+', '*', t)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.9 usec per loop
```

Note that re.sub will return a reference to the input string if it has found no matches, saving more wear and tear on your computer, instead of a whole new string.

Comment: +1 That's a good tip. Although for an average Joe who might not be doing this thousands of times per second, the difference hardly matters. The former wins on readability. So I'd suggest, don't blindly use the latter.

Comment: @Medorator Not sure about the legibility ... once JAvg understands `\X`, the jump to `\X\X` seems tiny to me. Perhaps `\X{2,}` would be better? I'd hope that JAvg wouldn't do anything blindly. If the output requirement changed to "find all occurrences of repeated asterisks", you'd like to think that the regex got changed from 1+ to 2+.

Comment: even faster:  "re.sub('\\*\\*\\*\*', '*', t)" : two same characters followed by 0 or more of the same (if speed matters)

Answer (score 11):

how about a non regex way

```
def squeeze(char,s):
    while char*2 in s:
        s=s.replace(char*2,char)
    return s
print(squeeze("*" , "AB***abc**def**AA***k"))
```

This returns `AB*abc*def*AA*k`

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest using the [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) sub function:

```
import re

result = re.sub("\*+", "*", "***abc**de*fg******h")
```

I highly recommend reading through the article about RE and good practices. They can be tricky if you're not familiar with them. In practice, using raw strings is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works well, I'm going to read through the article on RE to figure out what exactly is going on with the "\+" part of the code. I didn't know you could use multiple symbols in conjunction with each other. I thought you could only use "+" or "*" for example.

Comment: @NSchrading: In `"\\*+"`, I'm escaping the * character because it's a special re symbol. So I match a literal * character, and the + means one or more.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote:

```
pattern.replace("*"\*, "*")
```

You meant:

```
pattern.replace("\**", "*")
#                ^^^^
```

You really meant:

```
pattern_after_substitution= re.sub(r"\*+", "*", pattern)
```

which does what you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

I timed all the methods in the current answers (with Python 3.7.2, macOS High Sierra).

`b()` was the best overall, `c()` was best when no matches are made.

```
def b(text):
    re.sub(r"\*\*+", "*", text)

# aka squeeze()
def c(text):
    while "*" * 2 in text:
        text = text.replace("*" * 2, "*")
    return text
```

Input 1, no repeats: 
`'a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*'`

- a) 10000 loops, best of 5: 24.5 usec per loop
- b) 100000 loops, best of 5: 3.17 usec per loop
- **c) 500000 loops, best of 5: 508 nsec per loop**
- d) 10000 loops, best of 5: 25.4 usec per loop
- e) 5000 loops, best of 5: 44.7 usec per loop
- f) **500000 loops, best of 5: 522 nsec per loop**

Input 2, with repeats:
`'a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*****************************************************************************************************a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*'`

- a) 5000 loops, best of 5: 46.2 usec per loop
- b) **50000 loops, best of 5: 5.21 usec per loop**
- c) 20000 loops, best of 5: 13.4 usec per loop
- d) 5000 loops, best of 5: 47.4 usec per loop
- e) 2000 loops, best of 5: 103 usec per loop
- f) 20000 loops, best of 5: 13.1 usec per loop

[image: b() is best overall, c() best if no matches]

The methods:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
See which function variants are fastest. Run like:
python -mtimeit -s"import time_functions;t='a*'*100" "time_functions.a(t)"
python -mtimeit -s"import time_functions;t='a*'*100" "time_functions.b(t)"
etc.
"""
import re


def a(text):
    return re.sub(r"\*+", "*", text)


def b(text):
    re.sub(r"\*\*+", "*", text)


# aka squeeze()
def c(text):
    while "*" * 2 in text:
        text = text.replace("*" * 2, "*")
    return text


regex = re.compile(r"\*+")


# like a() but with (premature) optimisation
def d(text):
    return re.sub(regex, "*", text)


def e(text):
    return "".join(c for c, n in zip(text, text[1:] + " ") if c + n != "**")


def f(text):
    while True:
        if "**" in text:  # if two stars are in the variable pattern
            text = text.replace("**", "*")  # replace two stars with one
        else:  # otherwise
            break  # break from the infinite while loop
    return text
```

Answer (score 1):

Well regular expressions wise I would do exactly as JoshD has suggested. But one improvement here.

Use -

```
regex  = re.compile('\*+')
result = re.sub(regex, "*", string)
```

This would essentially cache your regex. So subsequent usage of this in a loop would make your regex operations fast.

Comment: This is a premature optimization. Python caches recently-used compiled regexes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub('\*+', '*', pattern)
```

That will do.

Answer (score 0):

without regexp you can use general repeating element removal with checking of '*':

```
source = "***abc**dee*fg******h"
target = ''.join(c for c,n in zip(source, source[1:]+' ') if  c+n != '**')
print target
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume for this sake of this example, your character is a space.

You can also do it this way:

```
while True:
    if "  " in pattern: # if two spaces are in the variable pattern
        pattern = pattern.replace("  ", " ") # replace two spaces with one
    else: # otherwise
        break # break from the infinite while loop
```

This:

```
File Type                       : Win32 EXE
File Type Extension             : exe
MIME Type                       : application/octet-stream
Machine Type                    : Intel 386 or later, and compatibles
Time Stamp                      : 2017:04:24 09:55:04-04:00
```

Becomes:

```
File Type : Win32 EXE
File Type Extension : exe
MIME Type : application/octet-stream
Machine Type : Intel 386 or later, and compatibles
Time Stamp : 2017:04:24 09:55:04-04:00
```

I find this is a little easier than having to muck around with the re module, which can get a little annoying sometimes (I think).

Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any number of consecutive asterisks, although you may need to replace the tilde with some other string that you know will be unique throughout the string.

```
    string = "begin*************end"

    string.replace("**", "~*").replace("*~", "").replace("~*", "*").replace("**", "*")
```

I believe regex approaches would be generally more computationally expensive than this.

Answer (score -1):

text = "aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccddddddaaaaaa"

result = " "

for char in text:

```
if len(result) > 0 and result[-1] == char:
    continue
else:
    result += char
```

print(result) # abcda

Comment: @Scratte My mistake.