# Python string replacement except first character

Tags: python, string

Writing a function that will replace every duplicate character of the first letter of a string with * except for the first letter itself - is there a more pythonic/elegant way to do it than this (lists, etc?)?

```
def specialreplace(s):
    firstchar = s[0]
    modifiedstr = s[1:].replace(firstchar, "*")
    print firstchar + modifiedstr

specialreplace('oompaloompa') ---> o*mpal**mpa
```

Comment: That looks like the best way according to the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Why would you not use that?

Comment: wondering what other similarly simple ways of going about it there are, if there are any. how would one do it with lists?

Comment: You could also employ a string.translate method for speed:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

But that is the best way.

Also, +1 for the Arrested Development reference.

Comment: Simple, readable and pythonic, I doubt you'll find any thing better (putting personal preferences aside).

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh mmm string translate.. with spicy club sauce. Can you show me how you would do it with string.translate?

Comment: The problem is it takes a few extra steps, so the speed improvements really only come if you're deleting characters (which you are not) or using the same protocol many times. I can post an answer below.

Comment: `s[0]+s[1:].translate(string.maketrans(s[0],"*")))`, still have to index and slice, what you are using is pretty much the idiomatic way

Comment: oh hey there again @PadraicCunningham! if i wanted to use a list of the string's characters, what would be the simplest script?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce do you mean multiple mappings?

Comment: Possibly use a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878555/how-to-replace-repeated-instances-of-a-character-with-a-single-instance-of-that

Comment: This question might have been a better fit on Code Review.

Answer (score 7):

It's a simple problem, I'm not sure why you're trying to complicate it. Your solution looks good, except for the fact that you should use .join() instead of '+' to join strings together.

```
"".join((s[0], s[1:].replace(s[0], "*"))
```

Comment: No you shouldn't use join. There's no reason to incur a function call here. See my edit for this.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I don't know what you mean by 'my edit', sorry.

What do you mean by 'function call'? The tiny overhead of calling join()?
join() is _the_ idiom for joining strings together, which is what we're doing here.

Comment: Check out the edit on this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30741141/4131059

I basically use dis.dis (a python bytecode analyzer for functions) to determine how the two differ, which is how the code is translated to byte code which is then run by the machine. Your method requires a lot of steps, including making a tuple, then calling a function, and then actually joining the string, when "+" just joins the strings.

Comment: `s[0]+ s[1:].replace(s[0], "*")`

Comment: Yes, if the program that's using this function was running too slowly, then after profiling it and identifying this very function as consuming a significant amout of time, I'd look into improving its performance. Since that's not what we're doing here and it's very unlikely to happen, I suggest sticking to recommended Python idioms, as stated in PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: That is for inplace string concatenation. This is not inplace. We are returning a new string here. We're not saying s = s[0] + s[1:].replace(s[0], "*")

We're returning a new string.

Comment: Right, so, what the OP asked for was " is there a more pythonic/elegant way to do it than this  (lists, etc?)". Now, what we're doing here is joining two strings together. It so happens that join() is the accepted Pythonic way of doing so. The performance differences between different methods of joining strings together are irrelevant here. Readability and conformance to the language's idioms is what counts. Now, you could argue that using '+' is as/more readable than join() in this case, since there are only 2 strings involved, but the decision should still be made based on readability.

Answer (score 2):

Here is not a recommended way to do it, unless you are iteratively doing this (for each letter, many times), but another way to do it:

And I was wrong on the speed. Plus different in Python3.

```
import string
a = 'ababc'
firstchar = a[0]
trantab = string.maketrans(firstchar, '*')

def translate(mystr, firschar):
    trantab = string.maketrans(firstchar, '*')
    return firstchar + string.translate(mystr[1:], trantab)

def translate_iter(mystr, firschar, trantab):
    return firstchar + string.translate(mystr[1:], trantab)

def replace(mystr, firstchar):
    return firstchar + mystr[1:].replace(firstchar, '*')

In [29]: %timeit translate(a, firstchar)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 582 ns per loop

In [30]: %timeit replace(a, firstchar)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 240 ns per loop

In [32]: %timeit translate_iter(a, firstchar, trantab)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 376 ns per loop
```

EDIT: Don't use join on strings. There's no reason to.

```
import dis
In [36]: def add(a,b):
    return a+b
   ....: 

In [37]: def join(a,b):
    return join((a,b))
   ....: 

In [42]: dis.dis(add)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE        

In [43]: dis.dis(join)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (join)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              9 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

You're incurring a pointless function call that makes no sense, makes the code less readable, and overall slows performance.

I'm all for sacrificing performance for readability, but not when it sacrifices both performance and readability.

Answer (score 2):

You could use enumerate:

```
print("".join(["*" if s[i] == s[0] and i != 0 else ch for i, ch in enumerate(s)]))
```

But that is just for fun, I would stick with your own solution.

To answer you comment, you can use multiple mappings to replace multiple characters with translate:

```
from string import maketrans
print(s[0]+s[1:].translate(maketrans(s[0]+s[2]+s[3],"*$!")))
o*$!al**$!a
```

In python3 you need a table using the ord of each character as the keys:

```
print(s[0]+s[1:].translate((dict(zip((ord(s[0]),ord(s[2]),ord(s[3])),"*$!")))))
o*$!al**$!a
```

You could also use re.sub ignoring the first character:

```
s = 'oompaloompa'

from re import sub

print(sub(r"(?<!^)"+s[0], "*", s))
o*mpal**mpa
```

But again a bit of overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You already are using list indexing and slicing, and you have a clean answer. Still:

```
def specialreplace(s):
    chars = [ ('*' if c == s[0] else c) for c in s[1:] ]
    print s[0] + ''.join(chars)
```

and if you want to codegolf that a bit:

```
specialreplace = lambda s:s[0]+''.join(['*'if c==s[0]else c for c in s[1:]])
```

Edit with shovelling a dictionary lookup with a default return value into it, because why not use the kitchen sink:

```
specialreplace=lambda s:s[0]+''.join([{s[0]:'*'}.get(c,c)for c in s[1:]])
```

Edit: @Voo's comment, The list comprehension is reasonably Pythonic - if you must use the list of characters as SpicyClubSauce requested, then you have as close to a ternary operator as Python has, and a join to bring the list of characters back together. The lambda versions are very unPythonic. All of them are less elegant than the questioner's original solution.

Comment: Neither of those two is more elegant or more pythonic than the posted one.

Comment: it's ok - i later commented underneth that i'd also welcome creative alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good and I think the one way that can improve it, is getting ride of multiple indexing, and for that you can use `iter` function to convert your string to an iterator that support `next` :

```
>>> def specialreplace(s):
...     it=iter(s)
...     first=next(it)
...     return first+''.join(it).replace(first,'*')
... 
>>> specialreplace(s)
'o*mpal**mpa'
```

Also as another alternative you can replace the `replace` method with a list comprehension and `join` :

```
def specialreplace(s):
    it=iter(s)
    first=next(it)
    return first+''.join(['*' if i == first else i for i in it])
```

The following benchmark says that there is no much difference between them but the second approach is a bit better.(for 1000000 loop and not for a long string test )

```
from timeit import timeit

s1="""
def specialreplace(s):
    firstchar = s[0]
    modifiedstr = s[1:].replace(firstchar, "*")
    print firstchar + modifiedstr
"""
s2="""
def specialreplace(s):
    it=iter(s)
    first=next(it)
    return first+''.join(['*' if i == first else i for i in it])

    """

s3="""
def specialreplace(s):
    it=iter(s)
    first=next(it)
    return first+''.join(it).replace(first,'*')

    """

print ' first: ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=1000000)
print 'second : ',timeit(stmt=s2, number=1000000)                                          
print '3rd : ',timeit(stmt=s3, number=1000000)
```

result :

```
first:  0.0531640987396
second :  0.0527780056
3rd :  0.0523271560669
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah I have! why?

Comment: Are you wearing your stevie wonder glasses again? ;) Run your first function and add the output

Comment: lol, I am seriously going to buy you some fishbowl specs! Run it again, you realise what str(object ) does? `return first+ "".join(it).replace(first,'*')`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham OMG!

Answer (score 1):

```
def specialreplace(s):
  return s[0]+s.replace(s[0],'*')[1:]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
Please consider to explain how this code snippet solves the issue stated in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pythonic way to do it using `str.replace()` method:

```py
string_  = 'oompaloompa'
new_string = string_[0]+string_.replace(string_[0],"*",string_.count(string_[0]))[1:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inputString = input("Enter a String: ")

def changeCharToAsterik(inputString):
    char = inputString[0]     # Assigns character at first index to char
    inputString = inputString.replace(char, '*')   # Replaces every character that is same as that of char to '*'
    return char + inputString[1:]  # Again the first character which was already replaced by '*' changes to char(i.e original character) and concatenates with rest of the strings from index 1 to last.

result = changeCharToAsterik(inputString)
print(result)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: I have now added comments to explain every steps, if that was what you've wanted.