# Python Regex to remove all line breaks to a single line

Tags: python, regex

I have an issue where line returns are causing an issue in my API calls and I want to make sure that line returns don't mess up my json formatting.

The best way I could think of was to remove all line breaks to keep all text on a single line. I have tried ways like `re.sub(r'\s+', '',{{test\n\ntext\n\netc.}})` or replacing `\n` and `\r` but it results in text like

test

text

etc.

on separate lines. How can I adjust this to something like test | text | etc. ?

Comment: I've tried your `re.sub` command and it works as expected with a single string containing line breaks. You'll probably need to provide more code for us to be able to see the problem. Specifically, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). is the best way to get good help. Also, if you're having problems with line breaks in JSON, it sounds like you probably have much more significant problems than this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace` to replace `\n` with empty sequence:

```
str = "{test\n\ntext\nnetc."
print(str.replace("\n",""))
```

If you want it to replace the new line with a `|` then write it like this:

```
str.replace("\n","|"))
```

Output:

```
{test||text|netc.
```

Edit:
Of course this will lead to having multiple | within your output. In order to reduce this for multiple new line occurences we can use a reducer method.

Here's one I found from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3878698/7813290).

```
def squeeze(char,s):
    while char*2 in s:
        s=s.replace(char*2,char)
    return s
```

Using this you can see that it will output only one time for multiple occurences:

```
def squeeze(char,s):
    while char*2 in s:
        s=s.replace(char*2,char)
    return s

str = "{more\n\rdata\r\r\r\ntest\n\n\n\n\ntext\n\n\netc.}"
reducedNewLines = squeeze("\n", str)
reducedNewLines = reducedNewLines.replace("\r", "")  #take out all the \r as well
print(reducedNewLines.replace("\n"," | "))
```

Output:

```
{more | data | test | text | etc.}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
import re
txt = "Python\n Regex\n to remove all\r line breaks to\r a single line"
print(txt)
x = re.sub(r"\n|\r", "|", txt)
print(x)
```

- re.sub   Replaces one or many matches with a string.
- | acts as Either or character

Comment: Note the OP changed the question after you answered. (An SO no-no.)